# Configure git to allow cli push/pull without password prompt - netrc ignored?

Tags: git

I've just started a contract job, and have an account at the company git repository.  Problem is, the password given is alphanumeric gibberish, so I'd like to configure git to allow for password less push/pulls on my Ubuntu development box.

To do so, I've created a `.netrc` file with 0600 permissions in `$HOME` and added

```
machine companyserver.com
login jason
password aphanumeric_gibberish
```

The git clone command consists of

```
git clone jason@git.companyserver.com:/opt/git/jason.git
```

Even after deleting my local working copy and re-cloning the git repo to

```
/media/storage/code_projects/company_working_copy
```

I still get prompted for the password.

Based on these conditions, how can I implement a password-less push/pull using `.netrc`?

Comment: It's probably using ssh.  Set up some keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The url you are using the clone the company repo:

> ```
> jason@git.companyserver.com:/opt/git/jason.git
> ```

looks like an SSH url for Git, as specified at the [official Linux Kernel Git documentation for `clone` urls](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html#_git_urls_a_id_urls_a):

> An alternative scp-like syntax may also be used with the ssh protocol:
>
> ```
> [user@]host.xz:path/to/repo.git/
> ```

In your case:

1. `user@` is `jason@`.
2. `host.xz` is `git.companyserver.com`.
3. `/path/to/repo.git/` is `/opt/git/jason.git`.

You'll need to set up an SSH key to use "password-less" push and pulls with your remote Git repo.  You can find such instructions at the [GitHub help page on generating SSH keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys).

Be warned, however, that it's recommended that you still encrypt your private SSH key with a password, because if someone manages to steal the private key file from your computer, then it's like stealing your password and they'll be able to impersonate you on any SSH service you use with that private key, as explained by [GitHub on why SSH passphrases are necessary](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#why-do-i-need-a-passphrase):

> Passwords aren't very secure, you already know this. If you use one that's easy to remember, it's easier to guess or brute-force. If you use one that's random, it's hard to remember and thus you're more inclined to write the password down. Both of these are Very Bad Things™. This is why you're using ssh keys.
>
> But using a key without a passphrase is basically the same as writing down that random password in a file on your computer. Anyone who gains access to your drive has gained access to every system you use that key with. This is also a Very Bad Thing™. The solution is obvious, add a passphrase.

In the same help article, they also explain [how to use the *nix utility `ssh-agent` to automatically store your passphrase during a terminal session](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#but-i-dont-want-to-enter-a-long-passphrase-every-time-i-use-the-key) so that you don't have to keep entering it every time you use your private key to make an SSH request.