# Git push using Ant

Tags: git, ant, ssh, git-push, git-pull

I'm trying to run `git push` command **wihout asking password**  using clear Ant , but I still had no luck.

I manage to run `git status`, `git commit`. And its clear why - this commands don't need any web access.Here is the code that I used for it:

```
<macrodef name="git">
    <attribute name="command" />
    <attribute name="dir" default="" />
    <element name="args" optional="true" />
    <sequential>
        <echo message="${git} @{command}" />
        <exec executable="${git}" dir="@{dir}">
            <arg value="@{command}" />
            <args/>
        </exec>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Http connection always asks user password, though i thought about SSH:

```
<target name="push_sshexec">
    <sshexec host="bitbucket.org"
             keyfile="${ssh.keyfile}"
             username="username"
             verbose="true"
             trust="true"
             command="${git}"/>
</target>
```

But it's failed with error at the point:

> > ```
> > Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
> > Next authentication method: publickey
> > Disconnecting from bitbucket.org port 22
> > *pathtoproject*\ant-for-git.xml:61: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
> > at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec.execute(SSHExec.java:218)
> > ```

When I try to do `push` and `pull` through SSH using GitBash everything is fine. Im sure that both private and public keys are what they should be (checked it several times).
I know that I'm missing something while connecting to my repository using Ant, but I don't see what is it.

I already read tonn of information, and didn't found what I need.

I will be glad for any advices and solutions.

P.S. I could write push method with JGit and import it to Ant build, but I really would like to make it at clear Ant.

**Screenshot:** [Working `git push` in cmd.exe but fail when running with Ant](http://fastpic.ru/view/57/2014/0210/c3fa965c8f927df98e18578e106cc0c2.png.html)

Comment: I think you forgot to add your public key to Bitbucket, see => http://guganeshan.com/blog/setting-up-git-and-tortoisegit-with-bitbucket-step-by-step.html

Comment: Maybe your private key encrypted with a passphrase ?

Comment: @Rebse no, I added key(

Comment: @Rebse Hm. Its encrypted with passphrase, but how could it prevent connecting?
When i did it with gitbash its ask the passphrase.

Comment: If your private key is encrypted with passphrase you will have to provide a password, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17764070/130683 and http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html for details or search for 'passwordless ssh' - what's your OS ?

Comment: Im using windows7. So I run the Pageant, added private key, provide the passphrase and left it running in tray.

Comment: @Rebse I had it before) it still doesn't work(

Comment: see this answer from serverfault for windows configuration => http://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-do-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key

Comment: @Rebse It helped me to make "git push" in cmd.exe but it still doesn't work in ant (screenshot added). What I've done is: moved id_rsa and id_rsa.pub to the GIT_HOME/.ssh/ location.

Comment: Ant uses JSch for it's ssh related tasks. Seems like the new JSch agent proxy
(https://github.com/ymnk/jsch-agent-proxy) for using pageant is not yet integrated in ant.
So best is to remove the passphrase from your private key. Alternatively run your build with
-Dkeypass=yourpasshrase to get your passphrase into sshexec task but that's very insecure.

Comment: @Rebse Thank you for help. I think that i will use Http and JGit to do it if its so.

Comment: The screenshot link sends you to a website that does a lot of bad things: redirects, many pop-ups.